# How to set recaptcha for Angular GET requests

Tags: angular, recaptcha

I want to set a reacptcha for the users who send a lot of GET requests, to try to prevent a Brute attack of some sort, is it possible to make a recaptcha?

Comment: To prevent Bruteattack, add logic in your server. A client should not handle this.

Comment: Here is implementation of recaptcha for angular. You need to implement client and server sides.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-recaptcha3

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ngx-captcha](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-captcha) need google key or this [ng-captcha](https://github.com/117028813/ng-captcha)